# Is it possible to pass somehow a parameter through the Linux bash pipe?

Tags: bash, curl, ftp, pipe, parameter-passing

I have two utility written in Ruby. Purpose of the first utility is nothing else, but reading a file from a http link, and dump its content to the STDOUT, very similar to cURL, lets call it "mycurl":

```
mycurl http://example.com/file123.txt
```

The second utility does nothing else, but uploads its STDIN to an FTP server and writes the content into a file with a given name, lets call it "myput". FTP server name and other options are hardcoded so no need for other options but the filename on the remote server. The two utility work together by piping the STDOUT of the first command (mycurl) to the STDIN of the second utility (myput):

```
mycurl http://example.com/file123.txt | myput file123.txt
```

They are separate utilities, because I often use them with other commands together. My problem is, that "mycurl" can determine the filename from the URL, but I still have to pass this option to the second command. It would be more convenient if the first command could somehow pass that filename to the second command through the pipe, or by any other method and I could write only this:

```
  mycurl http://example.com/file123.txt | myput
```

How can I achieve this? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Why don't you make the first line of input to `myput` be the name of the file?  Or even make it optional: i.e. if you invoke `myput` (or even `myput -`) then it will read the filename from the first line, otherwise it will expect an argument.

Comment: You might consider updating `mycurl` to take a program name as an argument, e.g `mycurl http://example.com/file123.txt -x myput`. This way `mycurl` could invoke `myput` with `file123.txt` in argv[1] and the HTTP response piped into its stdin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you won't change `mycurl` to print the URL to STDOUT and `myput` to parse it, or add a *save to file* option to `mycurl`, I don't think so.

The only way I can think of is saving the file name to a variable:

```
f=file123.txt; mycurl http://example.com/$f | myput $f
```

Comment: This wouldn't be useful in the case where the filename you get is not the same as what you think you requested in the URI.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a ruby developer, but this seems to work with `curl`. I'm sure you can adapt it to work with `mycurl`

```
require 'Open3'

Open3.popen3("curl -sJ http://example.com/file123.txt -w '%{url_effective}'  -o /dev/stderr") {|i,o,e,t|
  f = File.basename(o.read)
  $stdin.reopen(e)
  exec("myput "+f)
}
```